Unauthorized endpoint 401 for /services/data/v44.0/actions/standard/createServiceReport
I am trying to create a service report based on the documentation -
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.field_service_dev.meta/field_service_dev/fsl_dev_code_samples_sr.htm
Now whenever I call it from Apex, it always gives me 401 Unauthorized error.
Sample code -
String salesforceHost = System.Url.getOrgDomainUrl().toExternalForm();
        String url = salesforceHost + '/services/data/v44.0/actions/standard/createServiceReport';
        List<ContentVersion> version = [SELECT Id, VersionData FROM ContentVersion WHERE ContentDocumentId =: contentDocumentIds[0]];
        String base64String = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(version[0].VersionData);
        System.debug('content version data -->' + base64String);
        // Create HTTP request
        HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
        request.setEndpoint(url);
//        request.setEndpoint('callout:SelfAuth');
        request.setMethod('POST');
        request.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        request.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + UserInfo.getSessionId());
        System.debug('UserInfo.getSessionId() -->' + UserInfo.getSessionId());
        // Set the body as a JSON object
        request.setBody('{"inputs" : [ {"entityId" : "' + woId + '","signatures" : [{"data":"' + base64String + '","contentType":"image/png","name":"Customer Signature","signatureType":"Default","place":"San Francisco","signedBy":"John Doe","signedDate":"2024-06-05 12:00:00"}],"templateId" : "0SL2p000000KzIkGAK"} ]}');
        Http http = new Http();
        System.debug(request.getBody());
        HttpResponse response = http.send(request);
        // Parse the JSON response
        if (response.getStatusCode() != 201) {
            System.debug('The status code returned was not expected: ' +
                    response.getStatusCode() + ' ' + response.getStatus());
        } else {
            System.debug(response.getBody());
        }

I am not sure what may be the issue. With developer console I get a bad request so I assume issue is with calling it from Apex?
Thank you

Have you tried using request.setHeader('Authorization', 'OAuth ' + UserInfo.getSessionId()); as per the sample you were using? A SessionId and an Access Token aren't the same thing which could be why you're getting an unauthorised error.

Also, how is this apex being called?

I was able to solve it by using a Connected app with auth provider and finally using the auth provider in a named creds
